# How to remove SKU from product name in search results?

Tags: magento2, product, search, sku, category-view

How can I remove SKU from product name in search results?
In category view, product name is without SKU but when I search for some product, the results is including SKU in product name.

Comment: Can you please explain what is different happen between category and search page?

Comment: The difference is that in the category page all the products are shown with a image and name, but in the search results the products are shown with a image and name that also includes SKU. I want remove that SKU from name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace theme\mytheme\Model\Plugin;

class Product
{
     public function afterGetName(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result)
    {
      $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
      $requestInterface = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface');

      $routeName      = $requestInterface->getRouteName();

      if($routeName=='catalogsearch')
      {
          return str_replace ( $subject->getSku() , "",$result ) ;
      }
      return $result;
    }

}
```