# hide SKU in search results

Tags: magento2, search, search-result

How to hide SKU in search results. i want to show only price and description only.  i have try to edit this file

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml
```

And remove the SKU code but not working

Answer (score 1):

I have find the answer to my question, I go to this directory

```
/app/design/frontend/Vendor/Vendor_theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml
```

and I commented out this line

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo 'sku:' . $_product->getSku() ?>
```

it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/262193/108564). I think you are having the same problem. Hope this helps